# Linq Datatable separated comma

Tags: linq, datatable

There is a problem.

```
long d = (_dtGetDocumentsList.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.RowError == "Selected").Sum(order => order.Field("DebCre")));
```

Digits in `DebCre` are separated with `,` (group digit).

How can I remove `,` from this column before `SELECT`? Thanks

Comment: Can you expand your question more and use the appropriate markdown formatting for example code?

Comment: can you make your question more clear and undurstandable.